# Cannot start Appium server programmatically

Tags: c#, appium, winappdriver

I'd like to run an Appium server with default settings from C# like that:

```
AppiumLocalService appiumLocalService = AppiumLocalService.BuildDefaultService();
appiumLocalService.Start();
```

I also set the environment variables right before that:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(AppiumServiceConstants.NodeBinaryPath, @"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(AppiumServiceConstants.AppiumBinaryPath,@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\lib\main.js"
```

When I am trying to run the code is stopping for 2 minutes, and I get the following exception:

> Message: OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.Exceptions.AppiumServerHasNotBeenStartedLocallyException : The local appium server has not been started. The given Node.js executable: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe Arguments: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\lib\main.js" --port 4723 --address 127.0.0.1. 
>   Time 120000 ms for the service starting has been expired!

I Googled a lot, but I couldn't find the answer for that. I can start Appium manually from console or from Desktop Application without any problem.

- Appium Dotnet version: 3.0.0.2
- Appium version: 1.11.1
- Node.js version: v10.15.1

I appreciate any suggestion/help.

Comment: Does looking into the Windows Event Log help?

Comment: I didn't see anything there. What should I look for there?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

wrong:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(AppiumServiceConstants.AppiumBinaryPath,@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\lib\main.js"
```

Right:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(AppiumServiceConstants.AppiumBinaryPath,@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\***build***\lib\main.js"
```

So basicly the last directory is wrong in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem as well adding the right path to the PATH variable.

```
C:\>npm config get prefix
```

- add the prefix to system environment path
- Restart
- reinstall node.js to the latest version (typical installer)
- reinstall appium (by npm install -g appium)
- verify appium is able to run with the command: appium